# Overlapping DateTime Correction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have not written any SQL for an age an am struggle with the final stage of a data cleanup script. An example output of my existing script is

```
MRN ID     ADTM                    SDTM                    WardDays    WardMins
45  45_1   2016-03-24 06:28:00.000 2016-03-24 18:15:00.000 0           707
45  45_2   2016-03-24 11:07:00.000 2016-03-24 18:15:00.000 0           428

MRN ID     ADTM                    SDTM                    TDays   Tminutes
381 381_1  2016-01-30 00:25:00.000 2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 0       1415
381 381_1  2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 0       1013
381 381_2  2016-01-31 11:30:00.000 2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 0       323
381 381_3  2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 2016-02-01 17:50:00.000 0       427
381 381_3  2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 2016-02-01 17:50:00.000 0       1070
```

The problem is the overlapping dates for the same [non-unique] [ID] field. For the first case, the output I want (with *corrections in italics*) is:

```
MRN ID     ADTM                    SDTM                        WardDays    WardMins
45  45_1   2016-03-24 06:28:00.000 _2016-03-24 11:07:00.000_   0           335
45  45_2   2016-03-24 11:07:00.000 2016-03-24 18:15:00.000     0           428
```

and for the second set of records:

```
MRN ID    ADTM                    SDTM                        TDays   Tminutes
381 381_1  2016-01-30 00:25:00.000 _2016-01-31 00:00:00.000_   0       1415
381 381_1  2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 _2016-01-31 11:30:00.000_   0       690
381 381_2  2016-01-31 11:30:00.000 2016-01-31 16:53:00.000     0       323
381 381_3  2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 _2016-02-01 00:00:00.000_   0       427
381 381_3  2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 2016-02-01 17:50:00.000     0       1070
```

So you see that I don't want the end date-time [SDTM] of any two records to overlap with the next records start date-time [ADTM]. I see this being done in two stages:

1. Updates the dates according to the logic outlined by the data set above.
2. Update the TDays and TMinutes for each record.

To setup the data set, please use:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    MRN int, ID varchar(5), ADTM varchar(23), SDTM varchar(23), TDays int, TMinutes int);

INSERT INTO T
    (MRN, ID, ADTM, SDTM, TDays, TMinutes)
VALUES
    (45, '45_1', '2016-03-24 06:28:00.000', '2016-03-24 18:15:00.000', 0, 707),
    (45, '45_2', '2016-03-24 11:07:00.000', '2016-03-24 18:15:00.000', 0, 428),
    (381, '381_1', '2016-01-30 00:25:00.000', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', 0, 1415),
    (381, '381_1', '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', 0, 1013),
    (381, '381_3', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', '2016-02-01 17:50:00.000', 0, 427),
    (381, '381_3', '2016-02-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-02-01 17:50:00.000', 0, 1070),
    (381, '381_2', '2016-01-31 11:30:00.000', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', 0, 323);
```

For part 1. I have been toying with a CTE query, but this is merely merging overlapping records. I need to query the preceding record to check for the required conditions and I am getting lost big-time.

```
; WITH StartD AS
(
    SELECT ID, ADTM, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ADTM) AS Rn 
    FROM
        WD AS t
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM WD AS p 
            WHERE p.ID = t.ID 
                AND p.ADTM < t.ADTM  
                AND t.ADTM <= DATEADD(day, 1, p.SDTM) 
        )
) , EndD AS
(
    SELECT ID, SDTM, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SDTM) AS Rn 
    FROM
        WD AS t
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        ( 
            SELECT *
            FROM WD AS p
            WHERE p.ID = t.ID
                AND DATEADD(day, -1, p.ADTM) <= t.SDTM
                AND t.SDTM < p.SDTM
        )
) SELECT s.ID, s.ADTM, e.SDTM
  FROM StartD AS s JOIN EndD AS e
      ON  e.ID = s.ID AND e.Rn = s.Rn;
```

Can someone give me any advice about how this can be done?

Thanks for your time.

---

This case is not getting fixed with the accepted answer:

```
MRN ID     ADTM                    SDTM                    TDays   Tminutes
381 381_1  2016-01-30 00:25:00.000 2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 0       1415
381 381_2  2016-01-31 11:30:00.000 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 0       323
381 381_3  2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 0       1070
```

New table is:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    MRN int, ID varchar(5), ADTM varchar(23), SDTM varchar(23), TDays int, TMinutes int);

INSERT INTO T
    (MRN, ID, ADTM, SDTM, TDays, TMinutes)
VALUES
    (45, '45_1', '2016-03-24 06:28:00.000', '2016-03-24 18:15:00.000', 0, 707),
    (45, '45_2', '2016-03-24 11:07:00.000', '2016-03-24 18:15:00.000', 0, 428),
    (381, '381_1', '2016-01-30 00:25:00.000', '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000', 0, 1415),
    (381, '381_2', '2016-01-31 11:30:00.000', '2016-02-01 00:00:00.000', 0, 323),
    (381, '381_3', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', '2016-02-01 00:00:00.000', 0, 427);
```

Comment: In your sample setup the dates are defined as `varchar(23)` is that how they are defined in your actual database as well? (You refer to them as "date-time", and you use date functions on them, hence my confusion)

Comment: Sorry, i created this using SQLFIddle and it changed the types. I will edit now... They should be DATETIME.

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I need it to work on 2008 +. Happy to see 2012 only method though...

Comment: Is there really no column that contains data that ties rows together? I gather from your sample that sets of rows are related if they have the same value in the first *part* of `ID`, up until the underscore?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Okay, perhaps I have over simplified. There is another column that will help in id-ing the matching records. See edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you what you want in sql 2008

```
SELECT  t1.ID,
        t1.ADTM,
        COALESCE(t2.ADTM,t1.SDTM) SDTM,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t1.ADTM,COALESCE(t2.ADTM,t1.SDTM)) Tminutes
FROM    T t1
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                            *
                     FROM   T t2
                     WHERE  t2.MRN = t1.MRN
                            AND t2.ADTM > t1.ADTM
                            AND t2.ADTM <> t1.SDTM
                     ORDER BY adtm
                    ) t2
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

Comment: Great stuff this, sometimes I just can't get back into writing SQL freely when I have been away for an extended period. Thanks very much for your time it is most appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the right way to start:

```
declare @T table ( MRN int, ID varchar(5), ADTM varchar(23), SDTM varchar(23),
                  TDays int, TMinutes int);

INSERT INTO @T (MRN, ID, ADTM, SDTM, TDays, TMinutes) VALUES
(45, '45_1', '2016-03-24 06:28:00.000', '2016-03-24 18:15:00.000', 0, 707),
(45, '45_2', '2016-03-24 11:07:00.000', '2016-03-24 18:15:00.000', 0, 428),
(381, '381_1', '2016-01-30 00:25:00.000', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', 0, 1415),
(381, '381_1', '2016-01-31 00:00:00.000', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', 0, 1013),
(381, '381_3', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', '2016-02-01 17:50:00.000', 0, 427),
(381, '381_3', '2016-02-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-02-01 17:50:00.000', 0, 1070),
(381, '381_2', '2016-01-31 11:30:00.000', '2016-01-31 16:53:00.000', 0, 323);

;With Ordered as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MRN order by ADTM) as rn
    from
        @T
), Ends as (
    select
        o1.MRN,
        o1.ID,
        o1.ADTM,
        CASE WHEN o2.ADTM < o1.SDTM THEN o2.ADTM ELSE o1.SDTM END as SDTM
    from
        Ordered o1
            left join
        Ordered o2
            on
                o1.MRN = o2.MRN and
                o1.rn=  o2.rn - 1
)
select
    *,
    DATEDIFF(minute,ADTM,SDTM) as TMinutes
from Ends
```

Results:

```
MRN         ID    ADTM                    SDTM                    TMinutes
----------- ----- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
45          45_1  2016-03-24 06:28:00.000 2016-03-24 11:07:00.000 279
45          45_2  2016-03-24 11:07:00.000 2016-03-24 18:15:00.000 428
381         381_1 2016-01-30 00:25:00.000 2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 1415
381         381_1 2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 2016-01-31 11:30:00.000 690
381         381_2 2016-01-31 11:30:00.000 2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 323
381         381_3 2016-01-31 16:53:00.000 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 427
381         381_3 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 2016-02-01 17:50:00.000 1070
```

Unless your sample data is incomplete or I'm missing something, we just always match each row with the next row after (just sorting them by `ADTM`) and then either take the current `SDTM` or the next rows `ADTM`, whichever comes earlier (via the `CASE`).

Comment: Yeah, that's nice, sometimes I just can't get back into writing SQL freely when I have been away for an extended period. Thanks very much for your time it is most appreciated...